# (UWP) How to include a delay before buttons are enabled in a ContentDialog?

Tags: uwp

I have a system where the result of a ContentDialog dictates when a filter switches into a chemical sample. However, if the user immediately clicks "ok", the filter switches in too fast for the system's residence time to come back up to baseline. Since the ContentDialog also presents some useful info, I'd like to present it for 5 seconds before "ok" is enabled. This behavior is similar to when a user runs a downloaded executable in FireFox. There's a small delay before "run" is enabled. How can I accomplish this in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

After the user clicks the ContentDialog button, you can block the default shutdown behavior via `args.Cancel`.

```cs
private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = true;
    // do somethings
    this.Hide();
}
```

Best regards.